# Using generics for similar methods

Tags: java, generics

These two **Java** methods are very similar but I'm not sure how I can do code reuse. I tried creating a generic object `<T>` but it's not allowed because of the constructor. Can I use generics here? Or should `Event` and `Hotel` have a parent? I'm not sure if I can use an Interface here.

```
private List<Event> extractEvents(List<String> eventList) {
    return eventList.stream()
                    .map(eventName -> new Event(eventName))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private List<Hotel> extractHotels(List<String> hotelList) {
    return hotelList.stream()
                    .map(hotelName -> new Hotel(hotelName))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could pass in the mapper separately:

```
private <T> List<T> extract(List<String> list, Function<String, T> mapper) {
    return list.stream()
               .map(mapper)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

```
List<Event> r1 = extract(eventList, Event::new);
List<Hotel> r2 = extract(hotelList, Hotel::new);
```

Comment: You can make it even more generic: `private <T, R> List<R> extract(List<T> list, Function<T, R> mapper)`

Comment: It is sure more generic and have wider application, @Andreas. My 2-cents is that abstraction should stop at some level to maintain readability. If the method `extract` is expected to convert raw Strings to some kind custom objects, it's better to keep it as @Jorn Vernee suggests.

Comment: @DuongNguyen True, the more generic version should probably be called `mapAll` to reflect its general functionality. Of course, converting string to object is usually called parsing or unmarshaling, so `parseAll` might be better name for the `String` specific version.

Comment: Nice naming @Andreas. That also reckons such a method should better be supported by the language itself, some convenient `List.map`, `Set.map` to save some `.stream()` and `collect()`.